# R shuffle lists with repeated elements

Tags: r

I have multiple lists in R, each list has unique elements but some elements are in multiple lists. I want to shuffle the lists but also have each list have only unique elements. Here is something but this doesn't end up with unique lists at the end

```
x<-list()
x[[1]]<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
x[[2]]<-c(1,2,6,7,8)

u<-unlist(x)
x2<-relist(u[sample(length(u))],skeleton=x)

> x
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 6 7 8

> x2
[[1]]
[1] 4 8 3 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 2 1 2 1 7
```

Trying to figure out extra step to make sure each list has five unique numbers.

Comment: Do you want to make sure that all of the original numbers are used somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I want to just shuffle the lists up so say take the 5 and 8 and then switch them, also the lists might have different sizes.

Comment: `u <- unique(unlist(x)); x2 <- relist(replicate(2, sample(length(u), 5)), skeleton = x)`?

Comment: closer but the length 5 is hardcoded here, one list might have five elements and the other might have six elements though

Comment: I think people are misunderstanding your operation because "shuffle the lists" is vague. It would help if you would provide more detail in text about what you are doing: to me it looks like you (1) start with 2 vectors of equal length (does this need to generalize to more than 2 vectors? What about unequal lengths?), and that each vector has unique elements, but there is overlap in elements between the two vectors.  Then (2) you "shuffle" *all* the elements randomly and reassign them to two the two vectors (Does order within each vector matter? Or just which element ends up in which vector?).

Comment: The problem is that in the end you want each vector to contain only unique elements at the end - just like they were at the start. Is this all correct? And can you please address the questions in parentheses? This can be solved fairly trivially if there are always 2 vectors, but it is harder if there could be more...

Comment: 1. Order doesn't matter 2. I want to shuffle lists as in move elements from one list to the other, but at the end, each list has no duplicates 3. There may be 2 vectors, there may be 30 vectors, it varies. 4. There may be 5 elements in one list, and 10 elements in another. If it was an easy problem, I wouldnt be asking it here ;)

Comment: I don't have time to implement, but I would recommend the following algorithm: 1. Make a table of all your values *v*, sorted by *n* number of occurrences. 2. Within each *n* grouping, randomize the order of the values. 3. Initialize *k* output vectors of appropriate lengths filled by `NA`. 4. `for (i in 1:length(v)){` find the subset *k_i* of the *k* vectors that aren't full, randomly sample *n_i* of the *k_i* and replace the first missing value with *v_i* `}`. 5. Randomize the order of each *k_i*.

Comment: Yeah, thats pretty similar to what I ended up doing to just figure out a heuristic solution that works, maybe its impossible with a simple command given all of the constraints and needs to be an optimization problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the vectors already contain only unique values, so I think the solution can be as simple as:

```
x <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(1,2,6,7,8))

lapply(x, sample)

# [[1]]
# [1] 3 2 5 1 4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 6 7 2 8
```

Comment: this keeps elemets in the same list and just shuffles order. I want elements to be able to move form one list to the other.